# One Foriegn Key take two primary key in different table SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 3 tables, 2 tables have a primary key and 1 table have a foreign key
this is the example

```
TABLE 1
--------
Id1 INT PRIMARY KEY
Name

TABLE 2
-------
Id2  INT PRIMARY KEY
Name


TABLE 3
-------
Id (Foreign key Table 1 & Table 2)
```

The problem is when i insert some id in table 3 exist in table 1 and not exist in table 2 she give me error please some help ?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* define a column to have a foreign key relationship to two different tables:

```
constraint fk_table3_table1_name foreign key (name) references table1(name)
constraint fk_table3_table23_name foreign key (name) references table2(name)
```

However, that would require tha tthe `name` be in *both* the base tables.  So, in practice, tables are never really defined this way.

It sounds like you have a data modeling issue.  But you have not provided enough information in the question to provide a better answer.  One possibility is two columns and a generated column and check constraint:

```
create table table3 . . .
    name1 varchar(255),
    name2 varchar(255),
    name as (coalesce(name1, name2)),
    check (name1 is null or name2 is null),  -- at least one doesn't have a value
    constraint fk_table3_table1_name foreign key (name1) references table1(name)
    constraint fk_table3_table23_name foreign key (name2) references table2(name)
```

Note:  You also should not be using a string as a foreign key.  Number ids (ints) are a better choice.

Comment: she give me error 'name is invalid for use in 'FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT' because it is not persisted.'

Comment: @Marco_Paoulo . . . That is a typo.  The foreign key references should be referring to the base columns, not the computed column.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - "Numeric ids are a better choice" - So are you saying that you always use a surrogate key for PK even if there's a natural PK available (for example, a GUID that can serve as the PK, or multiple columns for PK)?  I know that Tom Kyte always used to say if there was a natural PK available, you should use it (reference: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:689240000346704229).

Comment: @dcp . . . It depends on a variety of factors, but I usually go in the direction of synthetic keys.  After all, a GUID is 16 bytes (which is used for every foreign key reference) and hard to type and read.  An integer is 4 bytes and much easier to write and read.